# Django rest framework modelviewsets custom response

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am very new to django rest framework and I have to customize `modelviewsets` and serializes to return response only success message instead of `queryset` when put method was called on .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `ModelViewSet` response to do this. I am assuming this is *only* in case of a `PUT` request. Then you can do this:

```
class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({"status": "Success"})  # Your override
```

This is the original code for `def update`:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)

    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
        # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(serializer.data)  # This is the original code
```

You can find it in the `UpdateModelMixin` in `DRF`

Comment: Thanks ... Exactly what  I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome; please accept the answer if your query is resolved